# How to get minutes listened via Spotify Web API?

Tags: spotify, webapi

I want to get the minutes listened for the signed in user.

There is no straight-forward way to do so mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/).

Initially, I thought of [getting user's top items](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-users-top-artists-and-tracks) and then calculating using each track's length and times played, but the response doesn't give the times played and the maximum number of items that can be obtained is limited to 50.

I'm pretty sure that this can be done because [this website](https://stats.fm/) does it.

Comment: Looking at the website linked (stats.fm), it looks like in their documentation it states a user has to requests their listening history by sending an email to spotify: https://support.spotistats.app/docs/import/streaming-history. In their app however, once a user links an account, the app can then start tracking the listening history.